# MySQL Query To PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql

I need the bellow MySQL query into PHP query, i really tried everyway but im still away from solution, thanks for answers.

```
UPDATE
    SCHOLAR_FILES
SET
    FILE_DATA = JSON_SET(
        FILE_DATA,
    REPLACE
        (
        REPLACE
            (
                JSON_SEARCH(
                    FILE_DATA,
                    "one",
                    2,
                    NULL,
                    "$**.ID"
                ),
                '"',
                ''
            ),
            ".ID",
            ".CONFIRMED"
    ),
    TRUE
    )
WHERE
    APPLICATION_ID = 1
```

When i running bellow code im getting syntax error.

```
$SQL = "UPDATE SCHOLAR_FILES SET FILE_DATA = JSON_SET( FILE_DATA, REPLACE ( REPLACE ( JSON_SEARCH( FILE_DATA, 'one', $ID, NULL, '$**.ID' ), '"', '' ), '.ID', '.CONFIRMED' ), $MARK_TYPE ) WHERE APPLICATION_ID = $APPLICATION_ID";
```

Comment: Please show the exact error code. and please use prepared statements. to prevent sql injection

Comment: This problem may actually be solved with prepared statements.

Comment: Use `?` instead of `$APPLICATION_ID` and bind the value.

Comment: Hint: Watch which quotes you're using. Use single quotes for the string and double quotes within the string for SQL character data.

Comment: PHP will try to interpret $**.ID because it is inside double quotes. You’ll have to escape the dollar sign. You should also use a prepared statement. For a complicated string like this, that doesn’t need to interpret variables (if you use a prepared statement), look into the [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) syntax